# Console log adding spaces between each character

Tags: javascript

I wanted to have a console log of each socket message being sent down to the server, so I quickly wrapped `socket.io`'s `socket.emit` function

```
    var self = this;
    this.socket = io.connect();

    this.socket._emit = this.socket.emit;
    this.socket.emit = function(){
        console.log(...arguments[0]);
        self.socket._emit(...arguments);
    };
```

It works fine except for some bizarre console log printing. This happens on Chrome and Firefox. What is going on?

[image]

---

I did fix this by using `arguments[0]` instead of `...arguments[0]` but I'm still curious..

Comment: I suspect you have a string encoded as UTF-16

Comment: Can you further explain what that means in this context?

Comment: My guess was incorrect. I didn't know about the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Full answer coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) when used as the argument to a function call breaks the single string value into separate arguments for each character. The example below should make it clear.

```js
var str = "abc";
console.log(str);         // abc
console.log(...str);      // a b c
console.log("a","b","c"); // a b c

var ary = [...str];
console.log(ary);         // (3) ["a", "b", "c"]

showArgs(...str);
function showArgs(x, y, z){
  console.log(x); // a
  console.log(y); // b
  console.log(z); // c
}
```

Why were you using `console.log(...arguments[0])`? What did you hope/expect to happen by using the `...` there?

Comment: I used `...` to pass to the original function's implementation, and used it to print the arguments without thinking about it. It's still surprising because hovering over the `...` object shows the string as a string.